# Is it a good practice to do something based on other components name in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it considered a good practice to set a condition and run some code based on other component's name?

For example I have a reusable child component, and want one of it's methods to stop and not run when it is rendered as a child of a specific component, so I would have something like this inside that method:

```
   methodName() {
     if(this.$parent.$options.name == 'someSpecificName')
     {
        // prevent rest of the function if child of specific component
        return;
     }
     else {
        // continue the function when rendered inside other components
     }
   }
```

EDIT:
So to further clarify my question, I have a method inside the child component than runs normally when the particular event is fired, but what I want to do is prevent that method when it is being rendered inside of a specific parent component.

Comment: I've not used Vue, but can't you somehow pass what extra code to execute? For example, can't you have the parent pass as a callback or an option the functionality needed?

Comment: Your title and your question don't quite match. The title asks about doing something different based on the component's name, which **might** be reasonable in some limited cases. But the question asks about doing something different depending on the name of the parent container, which I frankly don't think would ever be reasonable. Have the parent container pass a flag to the child for whether it should run this bit of code.

Comment: What you are trying to do might be completely valid but it seems to be really fragile from what you have told us. Some details of the problem you are trying to solve may help us to provide a more suitable solution.

Comment: Look at my answer, you can still use that approach to stop the method from firing in a specific parent.

Answer (score 2):

I would instead set a Boolean prop in the child component and make the method fire, if that prop is set to true.

Example:

```
// Child component
props: {
  runSomeMethod: {
     type: Boolean,
     default: false
  }
},
mounted() {
   if (this.runSomeMethod) {
     this.functionToRun();
   }
}
methods: {
   functionToRun() {
      // some code
   }
}

// Parent
<template>
  <child-component
    :run-some-method="true">
  </child-component>
</template>
```